# How to diagnose a Windows XP hard crash

Tags: windows-xp, 64-bit, crash

I have a 64-bit Windows XP machine which has hard crashed several times today. The symptoms are that the screen just goes blank, then the reboot cycle starts. There is no blue screen and even though it is switched on, no crash dump file is created.

On all occasions it has happened during a period of high CPU/memory activity. I have run a full Dell diagnostics with no failures.

Any ideas how to track this down further?

Thanks.

Comment: What was the computer doing exactly during these "periods of high CPU/memory activity"?

Comment: Running a backtest of a trading strategy. This involves reading market data (from disk) and number crunching.

Answer (score 1):

Go to My Computer > Properties > Advanced > Startup and Recovery, and untick the Automatically Restart option. Then you might see a blue screen (worked for me, and revealed the famous IRQ NOT LESS OR EQUAL blue screen).